# how to configure zkUrl in phoenix-spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-phoenix

`zkUrl` just config one zookeeper `ip:port`. How can i config mutiple `ip:port`

```
spark.sparkContext
  .parallelize(dataSet)
  .saveToPhoenix(
    "\"tablename\"",
    Seq("PK", "col1", "col2", "col3"),
    zkUrl = Some("header1:2181}")
  )
```

Comment: zkUrl = Some("zk1,zk2,zk3:2181")

Comment: @vmaroli Could you tell me how did you get it how to config . I did not find the config method with mutiple "ip:port" on the official website

Comment: Seen this way of configuration in a HortonWorks SupportKB https://community.hortonworks.com/content/supportkb/48908/how-to-included-all-zookeeper-servers-in-connectio.html